# French Site Template isn't appearing in custom templates

Tags: 2007, site-template

I got tens of custom templates in english language but I just tried to add a french template of same site using

```
STSADM -o Addtemplate -filename -title
```

then did a IISReset, but when I go to Central Admin or try to create a new site through Site Actions I am not able to see that french template I just added, am not sure what could be the reason other then language pack ? but I did had french websites on same Virtual PC before which I can't find anymore.

Oh yeah I can also find/see that template if I do something like

```
STSADM -o enumtemplates -lcid ****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the French language pack on your Virtual PC and possibly install any custom WSP which might contain your French site templates.